# How to create a new session in spring?

Tags: java, spring, session

i am using spring 3 (annotations) with jsf, and i know how to create a session and how to invalidate it afterwards...

so when i login and use the logout button at the end, then everthing works great. but the problem is, the session remains if i don't click at the logout button. if i now log in with a different user, then the old session data remains - cause the old session wasn't invalidated.

so how can i force the system to create a new session if the old session wasn't invalidated?

Answer (score 15):

You should clear the session when the user logs in. This way, whether they've logged out or not, you're starting fresh:

```
@RequestMapping("login")
public String login(LoginForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

    session.invalidate();
    HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(); // create session

    // log the user in

    return "successPage";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Steve's answer is good. Just to add a bit more context, you should *always* invalidate and create a new session after a user authentication event as a best practice against session fixation attacks.

Another way to accomplish what you are looking to do is to use Spring Security. I'm not sure if you've considered it, but by default it will handle invalidating and generating new sessions upon each user login for you. Also, it has other features which you may or may not find useful. This link may be helpful: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html. Scroll to section "3.3.3/ Session Fixation Attack Protection" for relavent info to your question

Comment: you're right, looks like spring security is exactly what i was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To Create new session after logout check `session.isNew()` condition if **session is old** then call `invalidate()`. Redirect logout method to **/login** mapping. It checks session and **it will creates new session when you call** `invalidate()` method.

**Logout Code:**

```
@RequestMapping("/logout")
public String logout() {
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

**Login Code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    /*
     * create new session if session is not new
     */
    if (!session.isNew()) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    return "login";
}
```